# Fetching a file in a shell script within a concourse task gives file not found error

Tags: shell, concourse, concourse-task

My concourse task is something like this:

```
name: test
plan:
  - get: my-repo
  - task: my-task
    config:
      inputs:
      - name: my-repo  
      run:
        path: sh
        args: [my-repo/examples/run-this.sh]
```

And the shell script tries to fetch a file in so manner:

```
CONFIG_FILE=./$name.cfg
```

When I run the task, concourse throws this error

```
my-repo/examples/run-this.sh: line xx: can't open name.cfg: no such file
```

The location of the run-this.sh and name.cfg file are the same. Any pointers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Even though the two files share the same directory, the dot in `./name.cfg` uses current working directory as a reference point - so it's the directory **from which the script is called**, not the directory in which the script is stored.

The best option to get this to work seems to be to add some intelligence to `run-this.sh` to locate the `name.cfg` file based on its own relative location, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname $0)"
CONFIG_FILE="${SCRIPT_DIR}/name.cfg"

(...)
```